# Android App stop playing YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube

Okay, I made a Android app to load a website which has YouTube videos on it. I just used the `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` command to create a webviewer. That aspect was working great since I didn't want to have to learn how to use the YouTube API and work it into the app. All was going well until I received an email from Google saying they pulled my app off the market because it played YouTube videos in the background, which I hadn't even thought of. My question is, how do I stop this from happening? I don't really want to kill the app when focus is lost since I want them to stay where they were in the app, so is there any other way around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick.

`@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        myWebView.destroy();
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myWebView.destroy();
        finish();
    }`